# What are the Civilization V leader statuses?

Tags: civilization-5

How many, or what are, the different leader statuses in *Civilization V*? I've seen Neutral, Hostile and Friendly before (the Hostile one quite a lot actually), but just ran into one that was Afraid.

So what other ones are there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is:

- Neutral - This is the default state.
- Friendly - This occurs when you're doing something that the leader likes, for example, Russia likes nations that have a large territory (and many cities), and Mongolia likes nations that have a large army). Friendly does not indicate that they have (or even would like) a declaration of friendship with you, it just means they probably won't be attacking you any time soon (unless they're planning on stabbing you in the back).
- Hostile - This occurs when you continuously do something that the leader does not like, for example you continue to build cities near their territory. This state does not mean you're at war, but it's generally a precursor to war.
- Guarded - This occurs after someone has publicly denounced you. It is pretty much meaningless, but it can cause them to become hostile if you continue to provoke them
- Afraid - This is fairly rare, I've only encountered it a few times, but it occurs sometimes when your army is much larger than the leaders army, and they feel that they might come under attack sometime soon. Most of the time they'll turn guarded or hostile instead, but if their army is sufficiently weak and they don't have enough allies, then they'll be afraid instead. It also occurs fairly randomly sometimes, with the best nation being afraid of you even though you're weaker, not sure why, although sometimes it could be because you're close to winning. Mostly it tends to occur for any of the above reasons after you sign a peace treaty with the other nation that was offered by them.

I'm yet to see any more statuses, but I've been playing a long time, so I don't think there are any more.

Comment: I've had most of the other Civs be afraid when I researched the Manhattan Project, and got a few ICBMs....

Comment: There is also "Returned to Life", when you liberate another Civ's capital. I assume this means they can never hate you...

Comment: Also War (self explanatory) and Denouncing (for a single turn).

Comment: I find that, when near victory (or having used a nuke), all the Friendly become Afraid, and all the Neutral become Guarded. Denouncing is not a prerequisite for Guarded.

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are the possible statuses you can have with rival Civs:

- War
- Hostile
- Deceptive
- Guarded
- Afraid
- Friendly
- Neutral

[This FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/938528-sid-meiers-civilization-v/faqs/60981) seems to list all the Civilizations and their tendencies towards each.

Comment: I don't think Deceptive is actually a state, at least I've never seen it. I think he was just talking about how likely a nation is to say they're friendly while they're really working to destroy you. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Friendly; they have a positive view of you.
Neutral; the default starting diplomacy bias.
Guarded; they are wary of you and won't make fair trades.
Hostile; they don't like you and think they could take you on.
Deceptive; hidden state, but is pretty much hostile with friendly shown.
Afraid; they fear you and your progress.